# How could I use AI to process a sentence, sum it up in a few words, and create a new column out of those words?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence

I have a column in my dataset that contains text (A few sentences) explaining why a delivery was late. There are tens of thousands of entries in this column and I would like to create a supplementary column that sums these sentences up in one or two words for analysis purposes.

I am relatively new to world of NLP, all I know is that ChatGPT is able to execute my requests with acceptable accuracy. I just would like to know how to implement this on a large scale.

For Example:
"Accident on the 401 highway caused shipping delays" --> 'Roadblock'
"Unable to verify shipping address, needed to contact customer" --> 'Address Misinput'

These are just some examples, I don't need it to be this specific.

I've already tried code in SQL that count the amount of time each word was used and I manually sorted out the verbs, however, I want to see what AI is capable of as it can understand complex questions and generate a coherent response.

Comment: So you have tens of thousand of entries; but how many distinct labels do you have? "roadblock" and "address misinput" are 2, I expect there are not too many distinct possible labels?

Comment: @Stef "Roadblock" and "Address Misinput" were just two demo examples I made up, but  I'd estimate that around 10-15 distinct labels would provide coverage for at least 90% of late delivery explanations.

Comment: That's very good! We can expect good results even with simple algorithms. If I had your problem, then as a first approach I would split the sentences into lists of words, run [MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) on the lists of words, and then use a [random forest](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#forests-of-randomized-trees) on the resulting binary vectors to try to classify them into your labels.

Comment: As a more powerful approach you could try sentence embeddings instead of the very simple multilabelbinarizer, but that shouldn't be the first approach.

Comment: (Note the approach in my previous comments are ***supervised*** machine learning, which means you need to provide some labels manually so that the machine can learn from those examples.)